# How do I insert a period in all filenames of a certain pattern?

Tags: bash

In a bash shell, I have a directory with files:

```
my.file.name0000.h5
my.file.name0001.h5
...
my.file.name0100.h5
```

How can I batch rename them all to insert a period before the digits?

```
my.file.name.0000.h5
my.file.name.0001.h5
...
my.file.name.0100.h5
```

I've tried looking into regular expression, and while I'm familiar with how some individual commands work, I am unfamiliar with how to put them together for my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why regular expressions? If you have [util-linux rename](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) (watch out! some have [perl rename](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/File-Rename/rename.PL), which is different), just:

```
rename file.name file.name. *.h5
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an example using [this source](http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/shellscripting/batch_rename). Applying that to your problem this should work.

```
for filename in my.file.name*; do echo mv \"$filename\" \"${filename//my.file.name/my.file.name.}\"; done | /bin/bash
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. After removing the `echo`I received the error `mv: cannot stat '"my.file.name0027.h5"': No such file or directory`